# Can I retrieve my activation and deactivation history?

Tags: applications, ios, iphone, find-my-iphone, history

I turned off my find my iphone in my settings about a year ago. My friend said that he swore it was on a couple of months ago and I swore that it wasn't because I just turned it back on today. Is there a way to check a history of that? We tried the email search but my email wasn't much help. Is there anything I can do to prove that its been off this whole time?

Answer (score 1):

**No**, no actual history or log of either activation of deactivation exists.

Apple, though, sends to your iCloud account an email whenever your device gets the **Find My Phone** feature **deactivated**.

Comment: Although it won't help in your particular case, I added the nuance regarding Apple's email as it might be useful to others.